# How to start an activity from flutter plugin using an API

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, flutter-plugin

So I am making a Flutter plugin and I am attempting to run Kotlin code on Android. The problem is, this code runs a method which attempts to start an activity without the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag on the intent. The problem with this is that it also does NOT have a way to give it an `intent instance` as it attempts to instantiate an instance inside the method itself. The method expects to be called from a button or other method that is stored on the UI and called from it. However, since it is called from the `onMethodCall` method in the Flutter plugin, it does not seem to work. I have attempted many workarounds such as adding a method inside the Activity and running the code inside while calling it from the flutter plugin class. I have also tried using the UIThread and no luck either. Any workarounds?

Note: I have not provided any code due to keeping this API hidden. It should only be known that I am running the code from the `onMethodCall` event.

Error: `Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?`

Comment: Have you some results?

Comment: @Alexufo It has been over a year since I've touched this area so I can't really remember what I did to get it to work somehow. I believe I ended up forking the API or something like that, though if I ever touch it again I'll be marking as solution whichever works if any.

Comment: Please make your problem statement as clear as possible. It's hard to read through and understand yours.

Answer (score 3):

You can extend your plugin to implement `ActivityAware` in your plugin class, when you implement it, you get a couple of callbacks that gives you the current activity. Like this :

```
lateinit activity: Activity? = null
override fun onDetachedFromActivity() {
    activity = null
  }

  override fun onReattachedToActivityForConfigChanges(binding: ActivityPluginBinding) {
    activity = binding.activity
  }

  override fun onAttachedToActivity(binding: ActivityPluginBinding) {
    activity = binding.activity
  }

  override fun onDetachedFromActivityForConfigChanges() {
    activity = null
  }
```

After that you can just startActivity from the assigned activity variable.

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Is it possible to open ui activity and get data back?

Comment: You can open activity and listen onActivityResult and pass that data back to Flutter

Comment: Visit following link for official documentation :

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Experimental:-Create-Flutter-Plugin

Comment: Hi Jav, in am getting in startActivity

 Intent intent = new Intent(this.context, DummyActivity.class);
      ((Activity)context).startActivity(intent); 


error,


constructor in class Plugin cannot be applied to given types;
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.example.coindcx_kyc.CoindcxKycPlugin());
                                   ^                                    


I got context from,

  @Override
  public void onAttachedToEngine(@NonNull FlutterPluginBinding flutterPluginBinding) {
context = flutterPluginBinding.getApplicationContext();
  }

Comment: Hi @JavT I am having a recylerView and in a fragment and each item is a card, out of which 1 of the card is a flutter module. I am trying to display it using Flutter as a fragment and also using FlutterView, but no luck. Can you help me with this?

Comment: @NadeemShaikh you dont have to make each module a flutter independent view, just call a lfutter component and send the data so internally in your flutter code you can determine which one to show, make sense? if not write me back and I will try to help you further

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, For Flutter plugin any platform-dependent logics should be kept in the subclass of FlutterActivity which was used to show flutter module/screens inside a native module. Now you can launch intent from that subclass without any additional flags.

@note - Subclass of FlutterActvity should be kept in the native module.

```
    class FlutterResponseActivity : FlutterActivity() {
        private var methodResult: Result? = null
        override fun provideFlutterEngine(context: Context): FlutterEngine? {
            return MyApplication.mContext.flutterEngine //Pre-warmed flutter engine
        }

        override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine)
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            when (call.method) {
                "startMainActivity" -> {
                    startMainActivity()
                    result.success(true)
                }
                else -> result.notImplemented()
            }
        }
    }

        private fun startMainActivity() {
             val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well I have no doubt that this code could work, but I'm trying to achieve this in a Flutter plugin that would need little to no manual configuration of native code besides the URL schemes and such. I would like to take another look if you can reassure it's usable in a plugin environment. Just from a quick glance, it looks like a solution for a Flutter app, not for a Flutter Plugin. A simple workaround I assume would make the class implement and register the interface, but I would like to avoid doing this since it would make the plugin less developer friendly in my opinion.

Comment: @Fern you can also try deep linking and launching URI from the dart plugin. Never tried this but I think this should do the trick

Comment: @Tamil Arasu have you example how to call android activity from plugin?

Comment: copy the above code and add ``` activity.startActivity( <INTENT()> ) ```