# How to start the main app's MainActivity from Flutter plugin

Tags: java, flutter, kotlin

I'm working on a Flutter plugin. How can I open the MainActivity of the app from an activity of the plugin (Java/Kotlin)? (the MainActivity is closed) Thanks

Comment: When you run your Flutter app, that *is* the MainActivity. If you want to open another Activity, use an Intent https://pub.dev/packages/intent

Comment: In the main app yes, but here I'm talking about a plugin. From there I don't have access to the Flutter app's MainActivity.kt.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61780966/how-to-start-an-activity-from-flutter-plugin-using-an-api

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it using a Flutter method but the following solution worked for me: [Android : Call activity of another application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960709/android-call-activity-of-another-application)